# Is the atman in every being eternally unique and fundamentally individual?

Tags: upanishads, atma, gita

In the Gita Krishna uses the word soul seemingly ambiguously, as it might be taken to mean the universal soul in the first few chapters, and the individual soul in the later chapters when he is describing a "rare soul" that realise its universal aspects.
Is the innermost essence of every being also individual as well as universal, or is every beings soul the same as every others?

Comment: According to whom?? Advaitins would say fundamentally individual. Dwaitis would say its unique. The answer to your question is not settled and is still being debated upon.

Comment: According to foundational scripture I guess.

Comment: Also individual here is synonymous with unique.

Comment: Every person's soul is unique with its own set of accumulated Karma over infinite births, since this Brahma's(single unit of solidified formless Brahman) creation started. But the source of energy for a soul is one and same i.e. Supersoul Purusha or Brahman (Did you create your body or mind or this world? Just maintaining it) Its inherited from universal Supersoul based on Karmas and predefined universal laws, just like a child inherits monthly allowance from father. Avatars or Gods with occult spiritual powers are adults for Supersoul while munis/maunis(silent ones) disappear in Supersoul.

Comment: "BG 4.5: The Supreme Lord said: Both you and I have had many births, O Arjun. You have forgotten them, while I remember them all, O Parantapa."

Comment: lets say internet is god. mobiles are bodies and OS is the soul. all mobiles are given with standard options. but the way we use it decides the outcome.